# PayPal Sandbox - Invalid Billing Address

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm trying to test a purchase on a website I'm developing which uses WooCommerce. So, when I proceed to checkout and chose to pay without a PayPal account (this payment method still runs through PayPal's system) and use a credit card. I'm using a fake credit card that I generated in PayPal sandbox. When I type in all the correct details and attempt to continue with the payment, it returns an error that the billing address I used is invalid (the billing address I'm using is the address that PayPal Sandbox generated for me. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly contact PayPal Merchant Technical Services for further assistance on this issue.

https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask